# failing to make portfolio responsive

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, portfolio

i coded my portfoliowebsite myself and my code probably is a mess because i don't have that much experience with code.
The problem i'm having is to make the website responsive so it's also looking good on the phone.

I think the problem is that i used px instead of %, but i tried various stuff and it doesn't look like i want. The website is https://www.jessewensing.com

I'll post a part of the code.

```
.content {
    width: calc(100vw - 30%);
    position: relative;
    left: 30%;
    margin-top: -6%;
}

.menu-header {
    font-family: 'Akkurat';
    text-align: left;
}
.project-nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Akkurat';
}

img { 
cursor:s-resize;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #A9A9A9);
filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #A9A9A9);
top:-2%;
margin-top: 10%;
width:50%;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: left;
left:3%;
margin-left: 0;
padding: 0;
position: fixed;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
color:red;
}

p {

top: 10px;
right:3%;
font-family: 'Akkurat';
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
}
p.naam {
top:10px;
left:3%;
font-family: 'Akkurat';
position: fixed;
}

p.contact {
top:76%;
left:3%;
font-family: 'Akkurat';
position: fixed;
}


p.cv {
top:80%;
left:3%;
font-family: 'Akkurat';
position: fixed;
}

p.text {
margin-top: 106px;
right:3%;
font-family: 'Akkurat';
color:red;
}

</style>
```

[This is how i want it to look when using the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWa2F.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/f51xjnzu/

Comment: how do you want it to look like?

Comment: give us a working example, if you can provide a JSfiddle or some way to see your working project, then only someone can attend to try and help you, with this much little information you'e provided, community can not reproduce your issue. So kindly provide more details please

Comment: I'm sorry, i totally forgot.
I added the websitelink and a screenshot of i how i want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Making the website responsive occurs mainly in the stylesheet (css), using % will help instead of px or em, wrap your elements in div containers to help keep elements align when accessed from a smaller device/screen.

You will have to resize certain elements or even hide them at specific screen sizes using similar code to below:

```
@media 
only screen
 and (min-width : 1024px) {}
```

Check this website for more details:
https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/structuring_a_responsive_stylesheet

Hope this helps, good luck!